# One cell based on whether 10 out of 12 other cells is green?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

I'm trying to track my school attendance with Google Sheets. I need any 10 attendances out of 12, and I want to show in one cell whether I meet that criteria. Is there a way to format that, aka 10 out of the 12 previous cells in a column is green/has "yes" etc.?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this formula**

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B13, "=Yes")&"/"&COUNTA(B2:B13)
```

[image]

**Or this**

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B2:B13, "=Yes")>=10,"Criteria met", "Criteria not met")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Had to tweak it but made it work.